# Long hashCode returns same number for different objects in java

Tags: java, hashcode

Let's say I have this situation

```
    Long id = -1L;
    System.out.println( id.hashCode() );

    id = 0L;
    System.out.println( id.hashCode() );
```

And guess what? Both outputs give same number (0) ! My questions are:

1. Why this is happening ?
2. How can I ommit this and calculate proper hash for 0 and -1 ?

Thanks in advance for reply :)

Comment: You seem to be assuming that hashes are always unique. They're not. There are 2^64 longs, and 2^32 hash codes available... there will clearly be collisions. You should never assume that two values with the same hash code are equal. They just *might* be equal.

Comment: Well, I am aware that might some collisions, but i thought that will happen for larger number not for the nearest ones.

Comment: Apparently that's a dangerous assumption... and if you write your code to not assume that it can treat hash codes as ultimate arbiters of equality, it won't matter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *Why is this happening?*

Because the implementation of `Long.hashCode` is [as follows](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#hashCode%28%29):

> The result is the exclusive OR of the two halves of the primitive long value held by this Long object. That is, the hashcode is the value of the expression:
>
> ```
> (int)(this.longValue()^(this.longValue()>>>32))
> ```

---

> *How can I omit this and calculate proper hash for 0 and -1 ?*

These *are* proper hashes.  Hashes are not guaranteed to be unique; in fact they're guaranteed *not* to be unique if there are more than 2<sup>32</sup> possible input values.

If you want a different behaviour, you'd need to write a `MyInteger` class that behaves differently (although I suspect there's no real good reason to do so).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the hashing function, 2 different objects can have the same hash code.

From `Java` [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29).

> The general contract of hashCode is:
>
> Whenever it is invoked on the same object more than once during an execution of a Java application, the hashCode method must consistently
>   return the same integer, provided no information used in equals
>   comparisons on the object is modified. This integer need not remain
>   consistent from one execution of an application to another execution
>   of the same application.
>       If two objects are equal according to the equals(Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must
>   produce the same integer result.
>       It is not required that if two objects are unequal according to the equals(java.lang.Object) method, then calling the hashCode method
>   on each of the two objects must produce distinct integer results.
>   However, the programmer should be aware that producing distinct
>   integer results for unequal objects may improve the performance of
>   hash tables.
>
> As much as is reasonably practical, the hashCode method defined by
>   class Object does return distinct integers for distinct objects. (This
>   is typically implemented by converting the internal address of the
>   object into an integer, but this implementation technique is not
>   required by the JavaTM programming language.)